# Removeing duplicates from a list with LINQ, getting System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a large list using LINQ. It works well when I only have the first three lines in the Select statement, but when I add the remaining fields I get the error message System.Linq.Enumerable + WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2 [ConsumptionDto, System.String]. What am I doing wrong? See picture for result
[image]

```
public class ConsumptionDto
{
    public string VariantVersion { get; set; }
    public string TyreCombination { get; set; }
    public string WeightRange { get; set; }
    public double? FuelConsumptionCity { get; set; }
    public double? FuelConsumptionHighway { get; set; }
    public double? FuelConsumptionCombined { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double? Co2EmissionCity { get; set; }
    public double? Co2EmissionHighway { get; set; }
    public double? Co2EmissionCombined { get; set; }
    public string VehicleType { get; set; }
    public int WeightMax { get; set; }
    public int WeightMin { get; set; }
}

List<ConsumptionDto> consumptionDto_noDuplicates = new List<ConsumptionDto>();

consumptionDto_noDuplicates = consumptionDto
         .GroupBy(g => g.VariantVersion)
         .Select(x => new ConsumptionDto
                {
                    VariantVersion = x.Key,
                    WeightMax = x.Max(max => max.WeightMax),
                    WeightMin = x.Min(min => min.WeightMin),
                    WeightRange = x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString(),
                    Category = x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString(),
                    Co2EmissionCity = GetDouble(x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()),
                    Co2EmissionHighway = GetDouble(x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()),
                    Co2EmissionCombined = GetDouble(x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()),
                    FuelConsumptionCity = GetDouble(x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()),
                    FuelConsumptionHighway = GetDouble(x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()),
                    FuelConsumptionCombined = GetDouble(x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()),
                    TyreCombination = x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString(),
                    VehicleType = x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString()
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: `x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString(),` this code is used for all the properties, why? What you are seeing is not error message but it is the outcome of `x.Select(c => c.WeightRange).ToString(),`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. how would you solve it instead? My knowledge of LINQ in particular is limited. I can not find the right solution for this. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping a beginner at LINQ. I think I have found the solution to my problem. Feel free to comment if you think it is a good solution or if you would have done it differently. It's fun to learn from others!

```
                consumptionDto_noDuplicates = consumptionDto
                .GroupBy(g => g.VariantVersion)
                .Select(x => new ConsumptionDto
                {
                    VariantVersion = x.Key,
                    WeightMax = x.Max(max => max.WeightMax),
                    WeightMin = x.Min(min => min.WeightMin),
                    WeightRange = x.FirstOrDefault().WeightRange.ToString(),
                    Category = x.FirstOrDefault().Category.ToString(),
                    Co2EmissionCity = GetDouble(x.FirstOrDefault().Co2EmissionCity.ToString()),
                    Co2EmissionHighway = GetDouble(x.FirstOrDefault().Co2EmissionHighway.ToString()),
                    Co2EmissionCombined = GetDouble(x.FirstOrDefault().Co2EmissionCombined.ToString()),
                    FuelConsumptionCity = GetDouble(x.FirstOrDefault().FuelConsumptionCity.ToString()),
                    FuelConsumptionHighway = GetDouble(x.FirstOrDefault().FuelConsumptionHighway.ToString()),
                    FuelConsumptionCombined = GetDouble(x.FirstOrDefault().FuelConsumptionCombined.ToString()),
                    TyreCombination = x.FirstOrDefault().TyreCombination.ToString(),
                    VehicleType = x.FirstOrDefault().VehicleType.ToString()
                }).ToList();
```